# Reusable workflow not being invoked on release action in Github

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I hope someone can help me out with this github action issue.

I am trying to set a github action pipeline that parse the some tags and invoke another reusable workflow.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
name: release per tag

on:
  release:
    types: [ published ]

permissions:
  actions: write
  checks: write
  contents: write
  deployments: write
  issues: write
  packages: write
  pull-requests: write
  repository-projects: write
  security-events: write
  statuses: write


jobs:
  get_project_folder:
    name: "Find project folder"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      project_folder: ${{ steps.regex-match.outputs.name }}
    steps:
      - id: regex-match
        uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        with:
          text: ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
          regex: '.*(?=\-)'
      - id: to-variable
        run: echo "::set-output name=project_name::${{ steps.regex-match.outputs.match }}"

  build_release_package:
    name: "Invoke standard release tag yaml"
    uses: ./.github/workflows/standard_release_tag.yaml
    with:
      project_name: ${{ needs.get_project_folder.outputs.project_folder }}
      environment: Production
    secrets:
      INSTALL_PKG_PAT: ${{ secrets.INSTALL_PKG_PAT }}
      HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.HOST_URL }}
      ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      ENV: prod
```

Somehow this pipeline is not being able to call the standard_release_tag.yaml even it exists on the repository.

Is this something happened to anyone? I googled but only saw this happen for a different trigger event and was fixed by Github team.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by validating that the pipeline was invoking and old version of the yaml pipeline.